# Will Awakening let me tap all my lands and get them immediately untapped?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With the card [Awakening](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Awakening), could I tap all lands immediately after my untap step and then have them untap upon entering my upkeep? I ask this because I'm trying to maximize [Omnath, Locus of Mana](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Omnath%2C%20Locus%20of%20Mana) as my commander.

Comment: What game are you talking about? I am assuming Magic, but there are other games with similar terminology.

Comment: With the reference to "Omnath", it's definitely Magic

Answer (score 9):

You could use Awakening to tap your lands twice in one turn, but not exactly in the way you expect.

Starting with your untap step, play proceeds as follows:

1. Your [untap step](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Untap_Step) starts, and all of your permanents untap.
2. Your [upkeep step](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Upkeep_Step) starts, and Awakening's [triggered ability](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Triggered_ability) goes on the stack. You gain [priority](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/Timing_and_Priority). This is your first opportunity to do anything.
3. You can now tap your permanents to add mana to your mana pool.
4. Awakening's ability resolves, and all of your lands and creatures untap.